# Speed Up Text Search Query Large Data Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I'm hoping someone has a tip for me.  I have a query below which filters detail field in the #TempLogins table.  The details field is a text field which contains many types of text strings, some containing urls that have parts like "ResultID=5" which is what is contained in the ResultIDSearch and ResultSetIDSearch fields.  The records with entries like "ResultID=5" are the ones I'm trying to filter for.

The problem I have is that the query takes way too long to run.  The TempLogin table has around 200 K records and the TempSearch table has around 80 K records.

Any tips on how to rewrite or speed this query up would be greatly appreciated.

```
enter code here: select * from #TempLogins a where exists
                      (select 1 from #TempSearch t1 where 
                                 a.detail like '%' + t1.ResultIDSearch + '%'
                                 or 
                                 a.detail like '%' + t1.ResultSetIDSearch + '%')
```

Comment: What indexes have you created on these temp tables?  What does your query plan look like?  How much data are you comparing (200k records is meaningless without context of how much data is being stored)?  Way too much information missing for anyone to provide any response outside of shooting in the dark.  But in the spirit of shooting in the dark, you're probably needing an index on #TempLogins.detail.

Comment: google and learn about "covering indexes" and add them to your tables for this query.

Comment: @TabAlleman An index is not going to help a like %

Answer (score 0):

This is the join version but the problem is a like % is going to be a table scan
An index on #TempLogins.detail may help but I doubt it

```
select distinct a.* 
  from #TempLogins a
  join #TempSearch t1 
    on a.detail like '%' + t1.ResultIDSearch + '%'
    or a.detail like '%' + t1.ResultSetIDSearch + '%';
```

this might do better

```
select a.* 
  from #TempLogins a
  join #TempSearch t1 
    on a.detail like '%' + t1.ResultIDSearch + '%'
UNION
select a.* 
  from #TempLogins a
  join #TempSearch t1 
    on a.detail like '%' + t1.ResultSetIDSearch + '%'
```

If you can then parse the terms out of ResultIDSearch and ResultSetIDSearch and then join on an =

Answer (score 0):

you can try `PATINDEX`.. Sometimes it's faster than `LIKE % %`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #TempLogins a
WHERE
    EXISTS ( SELECT
                1
             FROM
                #TempSearch t1
             WHERE
                PATINDEX('%' + t1.ResultIDSearch + '%', a.detail) > 0           
                OR PATINDEX('%' + t1.ResultSetIDSearch + '%', a.detail) > 0           
    )
```